# XHTML JavaScript preload images before rest of page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, image, xhtml, preload

Is there anyway I can delay the display of the HTML code (page) until  some certain images are loaded so that the layout appears with the header images as well as the HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to do this? displaying pages lazily is a feature, not a bug; give your images the correct width/height so they don't change the page layout on load and you should be fine; preloading only makes sense for images which are not part of the default page structure because they are added later via scripting or hover effects

Comment: All I can say is that my client is an idiot and will not understand arguements...

Comment: Oh, and the layout doesn't flicker, sizes are already in place...

Comment: And if the user has javascript disabled they don't see anything. Btw, I don't know if it's true, but I've heard that Google tests if a pages text and background color are the same.. shouldn't surprise me if the also test for hidden content. Maybe you could tell your client that this is how the web works. You are making something that will not work in all browsers...

Comment: Well if I would implement a solution I would make it Progressive Enhancement so that anyone with or without JS can visit the page. And yeah, Googles does that as well as looking for display:none or invisible elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, but it's your responsibility to protect the clients from themselves - after all, you're the professional...

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
with (document.documentElement.style) {

  visibility = 'hidden';
  overflow = 'hidden';

  window.onload = function() {
    visibility = '';
    overflow = '';
  };
}​
//]]>
 </script>
</head>
```

**note:** using `display = 'none'` instead doesn't work in my (somewhat old) Opera 10.10 as the `onload` will fire immediately...

Also, this will delay displaying the page until *all* external resources have been loaded. If you only want to wait for certain images, you'll need a more sophisticated script (*untested*):

```
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
//]]>
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img stc="…" width="…" height="…" alt="…" class="preload">
  <!-- page contents… -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
    var remaining = 0;

    function listener() {
        if(!--remaining)
            document.documentElement.style.display = '';
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; ++i) {
        var img = document.images[i];
        if(/(^|\s)preload(\s|$)/.test(img.className) && !img.complete) {
            ++remaining;
            img.onload = listener;
            img.onerror = listener;
        }
    }
})();
//]]>
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph and thanks everyone for all your very helpful input.

Comment: I have decided NOT to do this after reading all that was said and seeing that such a solution would imply hiding and showing the body, I was hoping there was a more elegant way which there isn't. Again, thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I share Christoph's opinion, that a page should be shown to the user as fast as possible--even just parts of the page. It is annoying if nothing seems to happens.

But you can try

```
<body id='body' style='display:none;' 
      onload="document.getElementById('body').style.display='block';">
```

( or does also work

```
<body style='display:none;' onload="this.style.display='block';">
```

? -- need to try)

That would display the page after all images, scripts, stylesheets, and multimedia files are loaded.

Comment: afaik some browsers don't load images if they are `display:none` - use `visibility` instead (please confirm); also, your quotes don't nest correctly

Comment: I just tried with firefox 3.5, Chrome 6, MSIE8. I used an image with onload, and it worked on them (with display:none on body). But I advice against this.

Comment: And if the image for some reason isn't loaded, the page will not be visible since there isn't an onload-event.

Comment: I prefer Christoph's solution since it wouldn't 'destroy' anything if JavaScript isn't available.
Here we should use something like 
`<body id='body' onload="..."><script ...>document.getElementById('body').style.visibility='none';</script>` ... That would be a mess. And we still might have that problem that `onload` is never called, as some mentioned.

Comment: @some: thanks; according to my google-fu, at least Netscape 6 and Opera 8 did not load `display:none` images, but this doesn't seem to be a problem any longer...